# Add file attachment to default Joomla 2.5 contact form

Tags: php, forms, joomla

I have a website that is using the default Contact form along with other data from the Contacts component and I need to add a file upload function to it.

I know there are many form components out there, I have used many of them but this site is using the default contact form from the Contacts component and also some other contact data here and there. So I don't want to have to build a whole new Contact page and form just to add file uploading. The file I want to update is templates/TEMPLATENAME/html/com_contact/contact/default_form.php

I am not a programmer unfortunately and even though I found a possible solution here: http://www.rupostel.com/joomla/hacks/how-to-add-uploads-to-your-joomla-contact-form, I was not able to follow it completely. I downloaded and activated the plug-in but nothing showed up.

Can anyone assist?

Thanks in advance.

Paul

Comment: Let me know how hacking the core joomla contact component works out for you. Furthermore, let me know how getting infected with a WSO shell viewer goes.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy - This doesn't actually involve hacking into core files. It require a template override (for that specific reason). I don't see from this where security is an issue. The only problem I see is that it uses `$_FILES` rather than the Joomla coding standards >> `$input->files->get('...');`. Could mention why there are possible security risks with this code as it would actually be interesting to know for future reference :)

Comment: Doing it yourself as 'not a programmer' will leave yourself open to all sorts of attacks.  Giving people to upload files without proper safety precautions is a huge risk on any server.  Being that you're not a programmer (which is NOT a knock against you!), you may be unaware of how to avoid particularly dangerous things.  Your best bet is to you use one of the components out there where the developers have already coded for safety.